# JAX-RS/Jersey: How can I "inherit" @Provider fields?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, jersey, jax-rs

In JAX-RS one can define `@Provider`-annotated fields or inner-classes (such as for `MessageBodyReader` or `ExceptionMapper`).

Sadly, I can't inherit this logic from a super class. (When I do, JAX-RS simply ignores them.)

I have several JAX-RS resource classes, so I don't want to copy+paste these providers in each of them.

**So, how can I define providers in a project-"global" sense?**

Answer (score 0):

in your WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>
your.package.one;your.package.two
</param-value>
</init-param>
```